# Why is my genetic algorithm overfitting so much?

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, accuracy, overfitting, genetic-algorithms

I'm only training on a fraction of the data each generation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    # Load and preprocess the dataset
    file_path = 'link/to/winequality-red.csv'
    wine_data = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=',')
    X = wine_data.drop('quality', axis=1)
    y = wine_data['quality']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # Standardize the data
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

    def apply_operation(operation, feature, range_limits, scalar, data, previous_result):
        value = data[feature]
        in_range = ((len(range_limits) == 1 and ((operation == '<' and value < range_limits[0]) or (operation == '>' and value > range_limits[0]))) or 
                    (len(range_limits) == 2 and range_limits[0] <= value <= range_limits[1]))
        if in_range:
            if operation == '+':
                return previous_result + value * scalar
            elif operation == '-':
                return previous_result - value * scalar
            elif operation == '*':
                return previous_result * value * scalar
            elif operation == '/':
                return previous_result / (value * scalar + 1e-6)
        return previous_result

    # Genetic Algorithm Implementation
    def create_individual(num_features):
        operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        num_chunks = random.randint(10, 30)
        individual = []
        for _ in range(num_chunks):
            operation = random.choice(operations)
            feature = random.randint(0, num_features - 1)
            range_type = random.choice(['single', 'double'])
            if range_type == 'single':
                range_limit = [random.uniform(-3, 3)]  # Single limit
            else:
                range_limit = sorted([random.uniform(-3, 3) for _ in range(2)])  # Double limits
            scalar = random.uniform(-5, 5)
            individual.append((operation, feature, range_limit, scalar))
        return individual

    def crossover(parent1, parent2):
        # If either parent has only one chunk, return them as is
        if len(parent1) == 1 or len(parent2) == 1:
            return parent1, parent2

        crossover_point = random.randint(1, min(len(parent1), len(parent2)) - 1)
        child1 = parent1[:crossover_point] + parent2[crossover_point:]
        child2 = parent2[:crossover_point] + parent1[crossover_point:]
        return child1, child2


    def mutate(individual, num_features):
        mutation_rate = 0.05  # 5% mutation rate
        mutated_individual = []

        for chunk in individual:
            operation, feature, range_limits, scalar = chunk

            # Mutate scalar
            if random.random() < mutation_rate:
                scalar += random.normalvariate(0, 1)

            # Mutate range limits
            new_range_limits = []
            for limit in range_limits:
                if random.random() < mutation_rate:
                    new_range_limits.append(limit + random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1))
                else:
                    new_range_limits.append(limit)

            mutated_chunk = (operation, feature, new_range_limits, scalar)
            mutated_individual.append(mutated_chunk)

        return mutated_individual

    def evaluate(individual, data, labels):
        correct_predictions = 0

        for i in range(len(data)):
            result = 0

            # Check if data is a pandas DataFrame
            if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
                row = data.iloc[i, :]  # Access the i-th row correctly for DataFrame
            else:
                row = data[i]  # Access the i-th row correctly for numpy array

            for chunk in individual:
                operation, feature, range_limits, scalar = chunk
                result = apply_operation(operation, feature, range_limits, scalar, row, result)

            prediction = np.round(result)  # Adjusted for classification

            # Check if labels is a pandas Series
            if isinstance(labels, pd.Series):
                label = labels.iloc[i]  # Access label correctly for Series
            else:
                label = labels[i]  # Access label correctly for numpy array

            if prediction == label:
                correct_predictions += 1

        return correct_predictions / len(data)


    def evaluate_helper(args):
        individual, data, labels = args
        return evaluate(individual, data, labels)

    def evaluate_population(population, data, labels):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = list(executor.map(evaluate_helper, [(ind, data, labels) for ind in population]))
        return results

    # Genetic algorithm
    population_size = 5000
    num_features = X_train_scaled.shape[1]
    population = [create_individual(num_features) for _ in range(population_size)]

    # Initialize lists to store accuracies
    train_best_acc = []
    train_avg_acc = []
    test_best_acc = []
    test_avg_acc = []


    for generation in range(50):
        # Select a random subset of 20 samples from the training set
        sample_indices = np.random.choice(X_train_scaled.shape[0], 100, replace=False)
        X_train_subset = X_train_scaled[sample_indices]
        y_train_subset = y_train.iloc[sample_indices]

        # Parallel fitness evaluation for training data
        fitness_scores_train = evaluate_population(population, X_train_subset, y_train_subset)
        best_fitness_train = max(fitness_scores_train)
        average_fitness_train = sum(fitness_scores_train) / len(fitness_scores_train)
        train_best_acc.append(best_fitness_train)
        train_avg_acc.append(average_fitness_train)

        # Parallel fitness evaluation for testing data
        fitness_scores_test = evaluate_population(population, X_test_scaled, y_test)
        best_fitness_test = max(fitness_scores_test)
        average_fitness_test = sum(fitness_scores_test) / len(fitness_scores_test)
        test_best_acc.append(best_fitness_test)
        test_avg_acc.append(average_fitness_test)

        print(f"Generation {generation+1}: Best Fitness = {best_fitness_train}, Average Fitness = {average_fitness_train}, Best Test Fitness = {best_fitness_test}, Average Test Fitness = {average_fitness_test}")

        # Selection
        sorted_population = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(fitness_scores_train, population), key=lambda pair: pair[0], reverse=True)]
        population = sorted_population[:len(sorted_population) // 2]

        # Crossover and mutation
        while len(population) < population_size:
            parent1, parent2 = random.sample(population, 2)
            child1, child2 = crossover(parent1, parent2)
            population.append(mutate(child1, num_features))
            population.append(mutate(child2, num_features))

    # Final evaluation on test data
    test_fitness_scores = evaluate_population(population, X_test_scaled, y_test)
    test_best_fitness = max(test_fitness_scores)
    print(f"Final Test Set Best Fitness: {test_best_fitness}")

    # After the loop
    num_generations = len(train_best_acc)  # or len(train_avg_acc), len(test_best_acc), len(test_avg_acc)

    # Plotting
    generations = range(1, num_generations + 1)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(generations, train_best_acc, label='Training Best Accuracy', color='blue', linestyle='dashed')
    plt.plot(generations, train_avg_acc, label='Training Average Accuracy', color='blue')
    plt.plot(generations, test_best_acc, label='Testing Best Accuracy', color='red', linestyle='dashed')
    plt.plot(generations, test_avg_acc, label='Testing Average Accuracy', color='red')
    plt.xlabel('Generation')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.title('Training and Testing Accuracy over Generations')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Training accuracy is over double testing accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understand, **a genetic algorithm is not a model**, it's an optimization method. So, it doesn't overfit, your model overfits. As I see, your model has a symbolic form and you allowed it to be defined very broadly. All your genetic algorithm does is maximise your score; if your model complexity can be any size, it will explain your data extremely well and won't bother generalisation.

If I were in your shoes, **I would somehow constrain your model's complexity**. You might consider something like maximal number of operations or parameters, it's up to you, you know it best. A plus for you is that you know now that the system converges to a high score on the training set - now your work is to work through your model and there might not be a need to modify the mere GA you have implemented.

Comment: This is the right answer.  I'd just like to add that using a genetic algorithm as an optimizer can increase the likelihood of a model overfitting if it was already prone to do so.  A big part of the appeal of GAs over gradient descent algorithms is that mutation and crossover provide a mechanism to escape local minima, which means that if the complexity of your model vs the complexity of your data is already such that overfitting could be an issue, GA optimizers can make it worse by finding the absolute minniest mins for that data, but not necessarily the most generalizable ones.